# How to give precedence to join conditions in DB2 sql?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a join left join between table A and B on below given condition.

"Left" table A:

| name | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | NA | NA |
| TOM | NEW YORK | USA |

"Right" table B

| name | flag | site |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | NA | NA |
| TOM | CITY | NEW YORK |
| TOM | COUNTRY | USA |

Current result:

| name | flag | site |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | NA | NA |
| TOM | CITY | NEW YORK |
| TOM | COUNTRY | USA |

Expected result:

| name | flag | site |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | NA | NA |
| TOM | CITY | NEW YORK |

`ON (B.FLAG=NA AND B.SITE = NA AND A.NAME=B.NAME)`

`OR (B.FLAG=CITY AND B.SITE=A.CITY AND A.NAME= B.NAME)`

`OR (B.FLAG=COUNTRY AND B SITE=A.COUNTRY AND A.NAME=B.NAME)`

If not 1st ,then 2nd else 3rd condition

I want to give precedence to these three conditions that when 1st condition is satisfied, then the remaining two should not be considered.

If the second join condition is satisfied, then it should not join again as per second condition even if its possible.

Only one of the three join condition should used.

I am getting double rows because some rows satisfy both second and third condition which is not correct as per my requirement.

What should I add here? How can I achieve the desired precedence?

Comment: I think this is very difficult to answer without seeing your sample data and expected outcome. Could you please show this? Maybe provide a fiddle to allow people to replicate your issue? Generally your conditions seem to be too complex. Should simply be something like "a.name = b.name AND b.site IN (...) AND b.flag IN(...)".

Comment: "I am getting double records ..." - would SELECT **DISTINCT** do any good, then?

Comment: distinct wont help

Comment: @Littlefoot , i have added an example now.

Comment: Where did you get `SON` value in the `name` column in the output from? There is no such constant in the base tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH 
  A (name, city, country) AS
  (
    VALUES
      ('BOB',   'NA',       'NA')
    , ('TOM',   'NEW YORK', 'USA')
  )
, B (name, flag, site) AS
  (
    VALUES
      ('BOB',   'NA',       'NA')
    , ('TOM',   'CITY',     'NEW YORK')
    , ('TOM',   'COUNTRY',  'USA')
  )
SELECT 
  A.NAME
, COALESCE (B1.FLAG, B2.FLAG, B3.FLAG)  AS FLAG  
, COALESCE (B1.SITE, B2.SITE, B3.SITE)  AS SITE  
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B B1 ON (B1.FLAG, B1.SITE, B1.NAME) = ('NA',      'NA',       A.NAME)
LEFT JOIN B B2 ON (B2.FLAG, B2.SITE, B2.NAME) = ('CITY',    A.CITY,     A.NAME) AND B1.NAME IS NULL
LEFT JOIN B B3 ON (B3.FLAG, B3.SITE, B3.NAME) = ('COUNTRY', A.COUNTRY,  A.NAME) AND B1.NAME IS NULL AND B2.NAME IS NULL
```

| NAME | FLAG | SITE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | NA | NA |
| TOM | CITY | NEW YORK |

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets to separate different conditions. Otherwise, you may get wrong results. Try this.

```
( B.FLAG=NA AND B.SITE = NA AND A.NAME=B.NAME )
OR
(  B.FLAG=CITY AND B.SITE=A.CITY AND A.NAME= B.NAME )
OR 
( B.FLAG=COUNTRY AND B SITE=A.COUNTRY AND A.NAME=B.NAME )
```

Comment: yes all conditions are in () still same, no change.